# Jenkins running on WAS 8.5.5 with JDK 1.7

Tags: jenkins, websphere-8

We have Jenkins installed and running on a WebSphere Application Server.  We recently upgraded the server to version 8.5.5 and switched the profile to use JDK version 1.7.  Doing this Jenkins Crashes the WebSphere Application Server and we cannot tell why.  Any hints or suggestions on things to look at?  Switching the server back to JDK 1.6 seems to work just fine, can Jenkins not run on JDK 1.7 or is it something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?  Errors are printed to the logs?  The server process mysteriously stops?  A JVM error occurs and a core file is created?

Comment: The server process stops with a javacore.  Reading @coffeebreaks post the only thing I can tell in the javacore is that it was signaled by "1TISIGINFO Dump Event "traceassert" (00080000) received".

Comment: This sounds like an IBM Java issue.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that by crash the websphere application server you mean either a fatal error at startup or a java process crash. Those can have many causes.

Just to give some ideas, it may be related to the fact that you had somewhat customized your JDK install and forgot to re-apply those customization to your new JDK. Or that switching SDK requires you to switch command line options, or that you indeed hit an incompatible class in the stack, or that your process crash because of bad luck, etc.

So please find more information in the logs, either the corresponding stack traces in your WAS server logs or the [javacores crash files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21181068).

Please also report your jenkins version.

As for JDK 7 compatibility, latest jenkins itself should be compatible, yet some plugins [are not](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Some-plugins-do-not-compile-on-JDK7-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-com-sun-mirror-apt-AnnotationProcn-td4667163.html)

You may also want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411717/jenkins-on-websphere-reports-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-jenkins-model-jenki. Maybe you have the same issue.

If you indeed find out an incompatibility, please report an issue in [jenkins issue tracker](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS) and consider updating [the Jenkins Websphere wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+WebSphere).

Comment: Yes a javacore is produced.  Trying to look over the link you provided for reading the javacore is a little confusing as I cannot find some of the tags that are mentioned.  The only tag that I find is what caused the javacore and that is "1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "traceassert" (00080000) received".  Thinking it might be that we just installed the base version we did do any updates to the server but this same error occurs.  Any suggestions on how to continue?

Comment: You can maybe solve it using -Xshareclasses:none (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV15305). Otherwise 1. check that the error is the same, 2. read http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21181068 3. publish your core if you want some help analyzing it,  4. maybe consider reporting and issue to WAS and or your JVM provider.